# $Q=\{ 1,2,...n \}$. $S \subset Q$, let $p(S)$ be the product of elements of $S$, Find the sum of reciprocals $\frac{1}{p(S)}$ for all $S \subset Q$.

Tags: contest-math

Consider the set $Q=\{ 1,2,...n \}$. For each $S \subset Q$, let $p(S)$ be the product of elements of $S$, Find the sum of reciprocals $\frac{1}{p(S)}$ for all $S \subset Q$.

I have no idea how to start this. Any hint will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $n+1$. 
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{S\subseteq Q}\frac{1}{p(S)}=\frac{\sum_{S\subseteq Q}p(S)}{n!}=\frac{(1+1)(2+1)\cdots(n+1)}{n!}=n+1
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Oh, I think I understand how to obtain the first equality. After we expand the sum on the LHS, then equate all denominator to $n!$, then notice that numerator is just the summation of $p(S)$, am I right?

Comment: For the second equality, it is true because of the hint given by Hagen von Eitzen, right?

Answer (score 1):

This quantity is
$$\left.\prod_{q=1}^n \left(1+\frac{x}{q}\right)\right|_{x=1}$$
which is
$$\prod_{q=1}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)
= \prod_{q=1}^n \frac{q+1}{q} = n+1$$
by telescoping cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Looking at $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=1+a+b+c+ab+ac+bc+abc$, what do yo think $(1+1)(1+\frac12)(1+\frac13)\cdots(1+\frac1n)$ expands to?

Comment: $1 + \sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{k}}+$ sum of product of any two fractions + sum of product of any three fractions + ... + product of all fractions?

Comment: so $p(S)=\prod_{k=1}^n{(1+k)}-1$?